# Query discord api from webiste

Tags: api, discord

Is there a way to query the discord API without have a bot on a server.

I would like to retrieve my friends and my profile images and put it on a website I created.

I've done some research and only found stuff for discord bots.

Is what I want even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.
Take a look at [this](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-user) API route. You can just make a request there with the user id and get the whole [user object](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#user-object).
If you need more information on the API itself and how to use it check out the [Discord API Reference](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).